Seventies or sixties movie where creatures are unearthed from beneath the streets
I am trying to find the name of a movie I watched as a child in the seventies.  It was prior to 1979.
Under a city there was a gas leak, I think, and while being repaired these larvae / insect bodies were unearthed.   Right at the end of the movie, a devil like being was seen hanging in the sky, almost like a silhouette.
That’s all I remember as I was only about 8 or 9.   It was super scary.  Thanks.

Was it a live action film or was it animated? Did you see it at home or in a cinema?

Parts of this sound like Bug

Does this answer your question? Movie: Grasshoppers from Space?

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

Is this Quatermass and the Pit (1967)...?

A mysterious artifact is unearthed in London, and famous scientist Bernard Quatermass is called in to divine its origins and explain its strange effects on people.

The plot involves the remains of insectoid aliens being discovered beneath the streets of London.


Quatermass and the Pit (1967)

Near the end of the film, a large apparition of one of the aliens appears in the sky.


Quatermass and the Pit (1967)





One of my favorite movies. In the US it was known as Five Million Years to Earth.
